# Find the polar equation of the circle with center on the line theta = pi, of radius 1, and passing through the origin.

Tags: polar-coordinates

Question

Find the polar equation of the circle with center on the line theta = pi, of radius 1, and passing through the origin.

i set a point (a,pi) on the line and going to this equation

a = rsin(theta) but its wrong.

where did i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I wrote a solution. I understand passing through origin to mean you wanted the circle to pass through the origin. If you meant the line passes through the origin, just take the standard equation of the circle.

Comment: thanks for helping. I understand clearly this question now.

Comment: No problem and if this is what you are looking for, accept so the question closes.

Comment: We can’t tell you where you’re going wrong if you don’t show us your work. Please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points which correspond to $\theta = \pi$ are exactly those on the $x$-axis. If you want the circle to pass through the origin, the only way to do this is to have it being tangent to $(0,0)$ i.e it has center $(-1,0)$ or $(1,0)$. This equation is given by

$$r(\theta) = (\cos \theta \pm 1, \sin \theta); \ \theta \in [0,2\pi]$$

Comment: This isn’t a polar equation. It’s a cartesian vector equation with a misleadingly named parameter $\theta$. For a polar equation, you need to express the *scalar* $r$—the distance from the origin—as a function of the angle $\theta$, which, by the way, will not range from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: @amd: I know this is a vector parametrization. I simply polarized that x,y coordinates and parametrized the circle the OP wanted. This is what I understood it to mean at the time. However, this is easily manipulated if OP notices $x = \cos \theta +1 , y  = \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the polar equation of this circle, we can start with its cartesian equation $$(x+1)^2+y^2 = 1.$$ Expanding and rearranging this equation, we get $$x^2+2x+1+y^2 = 1 \\
x^2+y^2+2x = 0.$$ Finally, substitute $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ to make this $$r^2+2r\cos\theta=0.$$
This can also be derived somewhat indirectly by starting with the parametrization $x=\cos t-1$, $y=\sin t$. Note that the parameter $t$ is *not* the polar angle $\theta$.